# Series Expansion of $f(z) =$ $\frac{e^z}{z^3}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

I've come across this problem on my lecture book of Complex Variable Function,

> Expand $f(z) =$ $\frac{e^z}{z^3}$ into a power series on the $0 < |z| < \infty$ domain

so far I've been learning about the Taylor and Laurent series, so I'm thinking to turn the function to this form

$\frac{e^z}{z^3}$ $= e^z .$ $\frac{1}{z^3}$ then by expanding the $e^z$ I get

$\frac{e^z}{z^3}$ $=$ $( z +$ $\frac{z^2}{2!}$ $+$ $\frac{z^3}{3!}$ $+ ... +$ $\frac{z^n}{n!}$ $). $ $\frac{1}{z^3}$

Is this correct? since I'm not really sure about the next step.

any idea of starting point on how to solve this problem would really help, thank you

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  I think you're on the right track, except $e^z=\color{red}1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\cdots+\frac{z^n}{n!}+\cdots$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner thanks for the correction, any idea on the $\frac{1}{z^3}$ part? or I just multiply it?

Comment: I would just multiply it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track, but $$e^z=\color{red}1+z  +\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+ \cdots +\frac{z^n}{n!}+\color{red}\cdots  ,$$  so it's

$$\frac{e^z}{z^3}=\left(1+ z +\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+ \cdots +\frac{z^n}{n!}+\cdots\right)\cdot \frac{1}{z^3}.$$

Then just distribute the multiplication:

$$\frac{e^z}{z^3}=\dfrac1{z^3}+ \dfrac1{z^2} +\frac{1}{2!z}+\frac{1}{3!}+ \cdots +\frac{z^{n-3}}{n!}+\cdots    .$$

Comment: sorry for the late reply, thanks, I've submitted my works and it seems correct :)